# In HTML, what is the difference between accessing JavaScript code locally and accessing it from a webpage?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with Bootstrap and I'm trying to use the **bootstrap.min.js** script found [here](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js).

In my code, if I use the following script tag everything works as expected:

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Whereas if I save the code found at the above link into a file called *bootstrap.min.js* and run the following code, the script no longer works.

*Note: I'm saving the bootstrap file one directory above where my HTML is saved.*

```
<script src="../bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**If the first option works what am I doing wrong (or not doing) to make the second not work?**

I'm new to web development but from what I understand, when you use the `script` tags in HTML, all that happens is the script at the location specified in `src=" "` is run. Where in this case, both options seemingly point to the same code.

Comment: are you using Visual Studio, or something else? are you dragging and dropping the `bootstrap.min.js` file into your HTML code? or are you writing it manually?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by dragging and dropping the file. I copied and pasted the code from the first example into a file named bootstrap.min.js. Then in my HTML code I manually typed "<script src="/bootstrap.min.js"></script>".

Comment: If it is saved one directory above your HTML like you said use `<script src="../bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar Sorry, that's a typo in the question. I'm using `<script src="../bootstrap.min.js">`

Comment: that folder `bootstrap.min.js` isn't sitting in another folder? what about trying `<script src="~/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: How do you know it doesnt work? what is your test case? What did you use to save the file? Are you sure it is not saved as bootstrap.min.js.txt by mistake (common)?

Comment: It is actually sitting within another folder. The directory structure is: `Folder1 (bootstrap.min.js is here) -> Folder2 (index.php is here)`. With `Folder1` being in my home directory. Also changing to `~` unfortunately made no difference.

Comment: Use `<script src="../Folder1/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: then you have to change the src to include Folder1 `<script src="../Folder1//bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar Strangely enough, I'm successfully calling other files this way. For example: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../styles.css">` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>` are working fine (they are in the same directory as bootstrap.min.js). Also, my test case is to reload the webpage, I'm using sublime to save the file and I am sure it is not bootstrap.min.js.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your title, I have to delve into practices and ways of work.

CDN's (using a script from a link) isn't generally a good idea for development, as you don't have that script when offline and anything relying on that will fall over. However, it saves space (as you don't store the script), and it is quite manageable as well (with regards to directories and building doesn't modify the paths etc.). In development, local files are a good idea. In production, however, it is a good idea to either use minified JS, or CDN's, for storage saving.

In answer to your question body, you have to get the path right (including the file name). `..\` goes to the parent directory to start off with, while `.\` is the current directory. Also, the `<script>` reference tag has to be above all usages as the page is loaded from top to bottom. Take those tips and see what the issue is.

Comment: Thank you! Your very last point was the problem. It turns out I need to load jQuery before loading the Bootstrap scripts.

Comment: yes that might cause a few issues :-). bootstrap should have thrown an error in the browser console though...